including web application in bundle
I have the requirement to bundle a web application along with my app and load it in a web view. I'm referencing a dummy html file under assets/webApp for development which gets replaced by the actual web app bundle at build time. The problem is that the index html fails to load, as the referenced js files' "extension is not registered in assetExts". I can't however add "js" as an asset extension, because then the whole react native app fails to compile.
How can I solve this issue and why the heck is react native not simple taking whatever is in assets and treating it as an asset, i.e. why do I have to register the file extensions.
